# Updating treeview control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application as soon as an object is dropped on canvas I stored it in a tree. Now, I'm trying to write a method to delete an object which is fine but I also need to delete that specific object from the tree. Each object has a unique id so this way I can find it in tree and remove it from tree while being deleted from the canvas.

In order to find a node in tree I have planned to store ID in each node (item.Tag), however, I'm facing two problems:

1. How can I access to details of a node from a different class?   *myTreeObj.Items.Tag doesn't work properly.*
2. When I loop in tree myTreeObj.Items.Count shows more items that what I see.

Any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, TreeViews are actually what they say they are: a view of a data structure. In WinForms, you had to crawl up and down the nodes of a TreeView and add them or remove them manually. In WPF, the proper approach is to add or remove items from the actual data hierarchy (to which the TreeView is binding) and use PropertyChanged or CollectionChanged notifications to tell the TreeView to update itself automatically.

What you are trying to do may be possible, but it is going to be an uphill fight all the way, and things will not work as expected. WPF REALLY wants you to use databinding, and any other approach is going to give you headaches.

This article may be a helpful place to start understanding how to work with the WPF TreeView:
http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/05/24/the-wpf-treeview-is-a-view-of-a-tree/

EDIT:
The author's original article is actually more helpful:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode

Comment: You are right. it is time for me to understand the concept. Is MVVM part of this process?  Thank you!

Comment: @amitkohan - It is difficult to transition from WinForms to WPF because WPF introduces so many new concepts simultaneously. It helps to think of the User Interface as this dumb thing that just hooks up to the ViewModel. The ViewModel is where everything actually happens, but in a very abstract way. The topic is far too complex to get into in a stackoverflow comment stream, but the second referenced article above should help you get started.

Comment: Yes, that is right but before I get to the article on CodeProject I ran into this link and was hoping would give me a simple/quick tutorial http://www.skycoder.com/Articles/Article_77/Default.aspx  however, it seems incomplete ... these days finding a good WPF article or even step by step example is tough. After completing it I am getting an error as  **Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<myWPFTree.Node>' is less accessible than class 'myWPFTree.Nodes'**

Comment: Try making the myWPFTree.Nodes class public. (If you do not define an accessibility level, then the default is internal)

Comment: Also, if you are using .NET 3.5 then make sure that you are referencing the WindowsBase assembly in your ViewModel. ObservableCollection is defined the WindowsBase assembly prior to .NET 4.

Comment: The comments on the blog post you link to are not very promising. I think you might be better off finding a different tutorial/sample.

Comment: now compiler is not complaining about it but I gave up on it anyway since it is not a reliable method it seems.

Comment: I have gone over MVVM example on CodeProject(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) twice till got some ideas what it is ... however, I need to study more about it.  Now, my question is that in there we have an hard coded library as LibBusiness which reads Person information, what would be the case if we have are getting the data from a table using SP or Query?  I understand in Database.cs it uses  GetFamilyTree() to read the data but how that would work on a table?  Thank you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13259/discussion-between-cyborgx37-and-amit-kohan)